# Avoid log in prompt for Windows authentication website

Tags: asp.net, image, windows-authentication

My website has windows authentication and will allow only thoese users I mention in web.config file.The rest of the users should not be able to access the site so I have a denied.html page I want other users to get when they try to access.Following is my code.

In web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>    
<authorization>
  <allow users="domain\user1, domain\user2" />
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

In Application_EndRequest method of Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context.Response.Status.Substring(0, 3).Equals("401"))
    {
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        Server.Execute("~/Denied.html");
    }
}
```

In Denied.html

```
<img src="Images/Access_Denied.jpg" />
```

Now I have 2 questions for which I already tried and googled but couldn't find solution.

1) Users who do not have access, they get a dialog box asking them to enter their LAN credentials and only after 3 attempts, they get redirected to denied.html. Is there a way to avoid the log in prompt and get denied.html directly?

2) The image I am trying to load in denied.html is showing up in design of the page but not coming at run time, I just couldn't figure out why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer #1, but #2 happens because you denying access to the resources you config file.   You can override this in your web.config...

```
...
...
</system.web>
  <location path="Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already tried this but it didn't work out. Actually when I added the location path, I was getting an error 'It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition=’MachineToApplication’ beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS' and then googled to clear it but didn't succeed. The error goes away if I remove the authentication tag but that would allow all users access the site